# no user principal ad TEIID JDBC in custom translator

Tags: kerberos, redhat-datavirt

I have a succesful JDBC connection to TEIID using a kerberos ticket. I like to get the default principal that is in the ticket

Ticket details:
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:6003:6003
Default principal: nfunke@FUNKE.HK

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/21/2018 21:14:46  05/22/2018 21:14:44  krbtgt/FUNKE.HK@FUNKE.HK

but in the execute function of the translator, I am only getting the principal from the service, which is configured at data source.

Code:

```
public void execute(String tableName, List<String> columns, Map<String, List<Object>> values, Subject subject, Limit limit) throws IonicTranslatorException{
.
.
    if (subject!=null) {
users = subject.getPrincipals();
        for(Principal p: users){
            log.warn("available subject: " + p.getName());
            log.warn("Type:" + p.getClass().getName());
```

as a result I get:

.....  available subject: HTTP/52.201.217.84

.....  Type:org.jboss.security.SimplePrincipal

.....  available subject: Roles

.....  Type:org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup

.....  available subject: CallerPrincipal

.....  Type:org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup

.....  available subject: HTTP/52.201.217.84@FUNKE.HK

.....  Type:javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal

but no "nfunke"

where would I get the user name from the context?

below the domain configuration in standalone.xml:

```
            <security-domain name="FUNKE.HK">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="requisite">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
                        <module-option name="removeRealmFromPrincipal" value="true"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required" module="org.jboss.security.negotiation">
                        <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="userKeyTab" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/52.201.217.84@FUNKE.HK"/>
                        <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="keyTab" value="/etc/krb5.keytab"/>
                        <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="useTicketCache" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="refreshKrb5Config" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="isInitiator" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="delegationCredential" value="USE"/>
                        <module-option name="addGSSCredential" value="true"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

and yes, I can run queries with no problems

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delegate to data sources, first you need to define "security-domain" on your data source configuration. Then you need to define another security domain with "login-module" like above. See [Kerberos Delegation](https://teiid.gitbooks.io/documents/content/security/Data_Source_Security.html)

Comment: How about a translator, that is not a jndi data source? in my vdb it looks like this:
<vdb name="SECMETA" version="1">
<description/>

<property name="authentication-type" value="GSS"/>
<property name="security-domain" value="FUNKE.HK"/>

<model visible="true" name="IM">
   <source name="ionic" translator-name="ionic"/>
</model> for better readability I have attached the same code below in another answer

Comment: A translator is not a JNDI source. A connection to a data source is accessible through JNDI naming look up when the data source is deployed in WildFly server. If you want access to the correct subject, look in the ExecutionContext object in translator execute calls, find the CommandContext, on it you can get access to getSubject.